# Pygame weird effects on the screen, segmentation fault and crash

Tags: python, pygame, crash

I've been running into a serious issue these days, it's a segmentation fault (core dumped) error thrown by the terminal.

This problem occurs when I get back to the menu after losing and then playing it again.

Here is what happens exactly :

[image: segmentation fault error]

The window shown in the image above appears instantly and then closes.

Btw, the frames are limited to 50 in the game I'm working on and my laptop is a gaming one, so I don't know what's the reason of this crash, but I think it's due to the code.

Here is the piece of code that runs when I try to get back to the menu and then  play again:

```
# this is inside the main loop in the game function
for event in events:
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_c: # back to menu
            pygame.quit()
            main_menu()

# this is inside the main_menu() function
if play_button.get_rect(x=320, y=270).colliderect(cursor_rect) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        pygame.quit()
        pilot()
```

### UPDATE :

1. There is no specific error message that's being displayed when the error occurs but all error messages include the `core dumped` issue.

   e.g: `corrupted size vs. prev_size Aborted (core dumped)`
2. After some research, I found that the issue may be related to compatibility issues between pygame and Ubuntu (linux) and I'm by the way coding on Linux Mint.

Comment: we can't reproduce it only with this part of code. Better show minimal working code which we could copy and run to see problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you use `pygame.quit()`?

Comment: @furas I use it to close the current window and open the other one, because the game and the menu are each in a seperate window and each one of them has his main loop

Comment: @furas, there is no specific error message, every time the problem occurs, some new sort of error is displayed. In fact, it sometimes displays ``corrupted size vs. prev_size
Aborted (core dumped)``

Comment: I also use Linux Mint (now the newest 20.2 "Uma" but I started with 16.0) and I never had this problem. Do you run it in some IDE? Did you try it directly in terminal? PyGame uses C/C++ library `SDL` and maybe it needs to update. But I always run in one window - even if menu and game has own mainloop. Closing and opening window again is only waste of time. Do you run two windows at the same time? PyGame/SDL wasn't created to run two windows at the same time.

Comment: As for me problem can be closing and creating window again. PyGame/SDL was created to run only one window at the time. And `quit()` can remove some SDL elements from memory and `init()` may create them in different place in memory so it may need to recreate objects in PyGame to have access to correct places in memory.

Comment: @furas, I'm working on VS Code and I've never tried to run my code in the system's terminal. I don't run two windows at the time and I have never done that before. When I run my code, the menu pops up and when you I click the play button, the menu's window closes and the game's window appears and vice versa when I get back to the menu.

Comment: So what do you think I should do instead ?

Comment: Btw, I have the latest version of SDL which is 2.0.14

Comment: you should run `pygame.init()` only once at start, create `screen = pygama.display.set_mode(...)`  only once and send it as parameter `game(screen)`, `menu(screen)`, and use `quit()` only once when you exit program.

Comment: I found my example on GitHub but it keeps code in classes: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/stage-example/main.py

Comment: @furas, thanks a lot, I'll try that and I think it's gonna work

Comment: @furas, your solution worked ! Thank you! you can write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I've successfully fixed the issue and it was related to multiple `pygame.display.set_mode()` calls.

I had been creating a window for each of the menu and the game and this had resulted in a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

According to @furas in the comments, `pygame.init()` and `pygame.display.set_mode()` should only be called once , while `pygame.quit()` has to be called only when quitting the entire program.